# WCF Service Unable to start debugging on the web server

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, iis, visual-studio-2013

I am having an issue debugging my WCF service when I set the WCF service to *SSL Required* in my local IIS. I am able to hit the URL correctly for my service under http/https but I cannot debug and step through the code. I received a popup box with the following text:

> Unable to start debugging on the web server. The web server is not configured correctly.

When I make the service not *SSL Required* I am able to step through my code as expected. I am new to dealing with IIS and have gone through a number of tutorials with the same result. Any help would be awesome

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="sslBehaviorConfiguration">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="sslBindingConfiguration">
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="SslWCFProject.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="sslBehaviorConfiguration">
    <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="sslBindingConfiguration" contract="SslWCFProject.IService1" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<!--<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="https"/>
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>-->
```

Answer (score 0):

1) First, I recommend checking the IIS logs.  They are usually located in the following directory: C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles.  Just go into the W3SVC prefixed folder whose modification date most closely matches when you received the error.  Open the log for the correct day and see the error details.

2) If that reveals nothing, then check out the Windows Application log in your Event Viewer.

3) Do you have a certificate (e.g. self signing certificate) on your computer?  Is there a trusted site issue here?

Comment: Thank you for the help! From looking at the IIS logs I found that I was getting the following record: 2014-11-21 03:30:03 ::1 DEBUG /SslWCFProject/debugattach.aspx - 80 - ::1 - - 403 4 5 91. I am currently looking into the 403.4 status which I am seeing. To answer your question yes I have a self signing certificate which I am using for the service and I am not sure if there is a trusted site issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found my answer. It looks like the checkbox in IIS for the website for *Require SSL* is associated the client certificate and requiring a client certificate to access the service instead of the section which is below it (although I will need to select required in the future). For the post I found When this is checked off I cannot debug the service but I can attach to the process in order to debug it.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vijaysk/archive/2007/10/18/visual-studio-debugging-websites-that-require-client-certificates.aspx

If I am wrong please let me know. If I come across anything else I'll update this question again with my progress just to keep in documented.